# how to download data from the web and move them directly into google cloud storage

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-storage

I want to download data from an authorized web portal and store them in google data storage. Certainly I can download them to my desktop and then upload them to the data storage using gsutil. I wonder if it is possible to directly download and upload the data (between the webportal and google cloud storage) without going through my desktop. With that I think I can schedule such task regularly with google cronjob.

Comment: answer: yes. read this forum guidelines to go further. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @Zig Mandel, can you please direct me to some resource that can at least help me get started.

Comment: google for the "google cloud storage" api, show us specific issues with it to be on-topic on this forum.

Comment: thanks Zig. There are two ways of doing this, Storage Transfer Service and gsutil. It seems to me  Storage Transfer Service is preferred for online web data transfer, but I wonder if it support wildcard for filename, because in my case I will need to download daily files added everyday. Otherwise I need to find way to programmatically add new filename to the TSV file (the URL list)

Comment: seems you havent looked at the REST api

Comment: One question about the Storage Transfer Service, why do we need to specify size of the file and MD5 in addition to URL? I mean how can client know the file size and MD5 before downloading it.